# Indexing elements in hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Lets supose that I have a hash:

```
class MyHash
  H = { 1 => [1,2,3,4,5], 2 => [2,7,8,9,10] } 

  def self.get(id)
    # code
  end
end
```

How is the implementation for that method so that I can access the data this way?

```
element = MyHash.get 1
# => [1,2]
element = MyHash.get 6
# => [2,7]
element = MyHash.get 4
# => [1,5]
element = MyHash.get 5
# => [2,2]
```

I can write the method "manually" but maybe there is a simpler "rubyist" method to do that

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Your edit still does not specify what you want explain your logic like I want to get the location inside the combined Arrays and return...

Comment: do I have to write more logic than that?! its obvious, the get method receives the index of an element in the hash. BUT a hash can't be accesed this way, so the method should find the id position, and return the |k,v|. it is perfectly understandable.

Comment: It's obvious for you, not for us.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if `a = H.values.flatten #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, and `id` is an index into `a`, you want `MyHash.get(id)` to return `[k,a[id]]`, where `k` is the key of `H` whose value (array) `v` contains `a[id]`. Is that correct? Regardless, you need to to clarify the question. Feel free to lift or modify my words if you find them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
H = { 1 => [1,2,3,4,5], 2 => [6,7,8,9,10] } 
HINV = H.flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }
        .map.with_index { |(k,v),i| [i,[k,v]] }
        .to_h
  #=> {0=>[1, 1], 1=>[1, 2], 2=>[1, 3], 3=>[1, 4], 4=>[1, 5],
  #    5=>[2, 6], 6=>[2, 7], 7=>[2, 8], 8=>[2, 9], 9=>[2, 10]}

class MyHash
  def self.get(id)
    HINV[id]
  end
end

MyHash.get(1) #=> [1, 2]
MyHash.get(6) #=> [2, 7]
MyHash.get(4) #=> [1, 5]
```

There is, however, no need for the class `MyHash`:

```
HINV[1]       #=> [1, 2]
HINV[6]       #=> [2, 7]
HINV[4]       #=> [1, 5]
```

If you don't wish the hash to be a constant:

```
def invert_hash_by_values_index(h)
  Hash[h.flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }
   .map.with_index { |(k,v),i| [i,[k,v]] }]
end

h = { 1 => [1,2,3,4,5], 2 => [6,7,8,9,10] } 
hinv = invert_hash_by_values_index(h)
  #=> {0=>[1, 1], 1=>[1, 2], 2=>[1, 3], 3=>[1, 4], 4=>[1, 5],
  #    5=>[2, 6], 6=>[2, 7], 7=>[2, 8], 8=>[2, 9], 9=>[2, 10]}

hinv[1] #=> [1, 0]
hinv[6] #=> [2, 0]
hinv[4] #=> [1, 3]
```

Here I've used the class method [Hash::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), rather than instance method [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h), the latter having been added in Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Restructuring the data or writing a custom class like you've done here is immeasurably better than adding oddball methods to the core Hash class. Nice.

Comment: I couldnt try the code, because my interpreter doesnt have 'to_h'. I will give it a try later.

Comment: [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was introduced in Ruby 2.0. for earlier versions, `HINC = Hash[H.flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }.map.with_index { |(k,v),i| [i,[k,v]] }]`.